# Bash shell script for file validation not null and more than 20 characters

Tags: bash, shell

Sorry guys but i am complete new to shell and beginning to learn the concepts and syntax

Say i have a 10 files.csv in a directory and in each file i am trying to check/validate that each field is not null and below a 20 character limit. If it's not we skip the file and rule it invalid as it should exit the loop and go on to the next file if the 2 conditions are not met.

sample csv file with titles

```
name,price,descriptor
Car,50,Mustang
Car_,70,Audi A5
Bike,30,BMW)
SUV@,80,Fortuner+_
Car,75,Sierra
```

Comment: Sorry, SO is not for getting other people to write scripts for you. You have to make an attempt. If you can't get it working, post what you tried, and we'll show you where you went wrong and help you fix it.

Comment: awk(1) is your friend.

Comment: well TBH i only have the sudo/logic down. Would you provide me a good resource to start writing scripts?

Comment: @purplehaze if you don't know shell scripting, pick a language you do know. Any general purpose language can do what you're describing. As for a guide to getting started, [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/).

Comment: Use a [`for` loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs) to iterate over the files, and an [`if` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) to take action based on the test

Answer (score 0):

Some general advise:

use `awk -F", " {'print$2'}` to get the fields.

use `awk '{print length}'` to get the lengths of characters.

Iterate over the list of files and check for the conditions that you need.